# Handle PDF download campaigns using Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, pdf, cloud

Our client is using Web-to-Lead to generate leads from a Contact Us form in their website, so these leads can be used directly in Salesforce campaigns.

Some of these campaigns are mainly Newsletters subscriptions and others are PDF and Whitepaper downloads.

For the Newsletters I'm planning to use Marketing cloud with the Journey Builder and standard Profile center to handle the Newsletter campaigns.

However, for the PDF campaigns, I noticed that one subscriber could download a document multiple times, and for each download, a new lead record would be created generating duplicates.

We would like to a void that, is there a way to do that with marketing cloud? what would be the best practice to handle this kind of campaigns in Marketing cloud?

Comment: What is your flow like? It is directly to Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud at the same (or close) time? Or are you inputting into Salesforce, then using the connector to generate leads into Marketing Cloud?

Comment: We are getting the leads directly into Salesforce through the web form, and then using the connector to have them in a Synchronized data extension, so they can be used in Marketing Cloud.

Comment: In my opinion best practice would be to handle this on the Sales Cloud side of things or prior to it. I would create a 'new lead' flow, and then decide how you want that journey to look. You could handle this directly within Sales Cloud through flows or Process Builder, or via an IPaas like Tray.io or Zapier. Then, I would set your journey builder settings to only allow a lead to enter the flow one time. You will also want to do cleanup on your leads, because each new lead is adding a billable contact to your MC instance, costing you more $